# JSONArray is empty

Tags: java, mysql, json, arrays

I read data from a database (only the last row, I do it in my php file) what I want to do is to use the data of each field separately but the problem is that the JSONArray is empty I tried a lot of ways to do it looking for it in different posts but it´s always empty.

This is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    JSONArray jArray = null;
    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb=null;

    String ct_id;
    String ct_name;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
      //http post
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost= new HttpPost("http://xxx.php");


            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

         }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
         }
      //convert response to string
        try{
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
               sb = new StringBuilder();


               String line=null;
               while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                              sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result=sb.toString();
                }catch(Exception e){
                      Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                }
        //paring data

        try{
              jArray = new JSONArray(result);
              JSONObject json_data=null;
              for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                     json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                     ct_id=json_data.getString("fecha");
                     ct_name=json_data.getString("dia");
                 }
              }
              catch(JSONException e1){
                  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "JSON is empty" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              } catch (ParseException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
            }


    }
}
```

It always catchs JSONException e1.

Thank you everibody in advance

Comment: Are you sure the PHP is properly formatting the reply?

Comment: I see no reference whatsoever to PHP in this question.

Comment: Post the json string that gets transfered so it could be seen if the json is ok or not. Also if you add some headers, that might be helpful as well.

Comment: @Matt: It is in the tag.

Comment: @hakra I know. Where ***in the question*** is PHP ever mentioned?

Comment: @Matt: Right there in the tag. Tags are part of the question. But next to that, I have not spotted any more PHP. Why?

Comment: @hakra *Why is PHP tagged? The question has nothing to do with PHP.*

Comment: @Matt: Well, as always: The one asking the question knows more than you reading it, so he/she is in the better position to say so. You should be smart enough to wait until your question about PHP has been answered I'd say. Don't complain with me please, but meta-information can be useful, too.

Comment: @hakra When the question makes no reference to PHP ***at all*** I question the validity of the tag. Seeing as the PHP tag was removed, it would seem my suspicions were justified.

Comment: @Matt: I can understand that, but as the OP didn't answer to any comments so far, I would not yet judge in this case, however, I won't edit it back, too ;)

Comment: @Matt Umm, what? It's right there: `I read data from a database (only the last row, I do it in my php file)` AKA: The one he is calling through AJAX `HttpPost httppost= new HttpPost("http://xxx.php");`

Comment: @TheZ so, theoretically, you're advocating the use of a PHP tag in a question that asks "I use PHP on my site but I need help with this javascript..."?

Comment: @Matt Actually, it's Java (not javascript) and I still believe the source of the problem is the PHP code (since the OP wrote it, and OP's getting a JSON exception from the string)

Comment: @TheZ I said *theoretically*. I wasn't referring to this question in particular.

Comment: @Matt Well, _this question in particular_ might have an error in PHP code. So you can take your theory elsewhere, this isn't black and white here, this is real life with shades of gray. Perhaps you were looking for http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @TheZ my point is, the mere *mention* of a technology shouldn't automatically make tagging said technology valid. Unless OP asks directly about that technology the tag should not be used.

Comment: Hi everybody, I tagged PHP because I have a PHP file for the query to the database and I didn´t expect any discussion because of it

Comment: The problem is that the code enters in JSONException, it means that the JSONArray  is empty and it shouldn´t, that´s my doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in PHP file, JSON couldn´t understand the data and that is why it was empty, I changed it and now works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Check returned string in `result`. Probably there are not only json structure(errors, warning, etc..). JSON spellchecker: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thank you ruX, how do I have to use it? which code do I need to validate?

Comment: I take the data from a database not from a JSON. is that the missunderstanding??

Comment: Copy response from "http://xxx.php" from browser and paste to jsonlint to check generated output

Comment: I did it before, it says it´s not valid because it starts with ([{   instead of {

Comment: " it starts with ([{ instead of {": you answer yourself :) Check where php script output '(' symbol and remove it

Comment: I changed the php and now it starts with [{, how can I remove the [?

Comment: If your root element is array, response should starts with "[{"

Answer (score 0):

after checking the json response; better to try using GSON, much more convenient;

```
        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        JsonArray jArray;
if ( jsonParser.parse(result).isJsonArray() ) {
    jArray = jsonParser.parse(result).getAsJsonArray();
} 
else { jArray = new JsonArray(); }
```

Comment: For this I have to create a new class called JSONParser. I read it in this post http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ but it is to read from a JSON file not from a database, instead of that can I do it like in the example? thanks